# is Jquery $.POST asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ive been trying to create a div on my index page that onclick calls a js function that would submit the data to a php page for calculations and mysql queries. but not only does my chrome developers tools show that no POST request is even happening, but the page just refreshes the minute i click the submit button. my event handler on the main php page is onclick,
 which should lead to this function

```
    function submitvote(uv){
 $('#rank_IFC').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif">').show();
 var sortdata = $('ul.sort').sortable('toArray').join(',');
 var url= "results.php";
 $.post(url, {Tablename:uv, sortdata: sortdata}, function(){
     $('#rank_IFC').html('').show();
    });
    }
```

which should than lead to my php conditional,

```
  <?php  if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this    file directly');
   // Including file for the DB connection:
    require 'connect.php';

  // If the poll has been submitted:
  $tablename=$_POST['Tablename'];


   if($tablename=='IFC')
 {     

    $userOrder=$_POST['sortdata'];


// The data arrives as a comma-separated string,
// so we extract each post ids:
$data=explode(',',str_replace('li','',$_POST['sortdata']));



    // Getting the number of objects
list($tot_objects) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sort_objects"));

if(count($data)!=$tot_objects) die("Wrong data!");

foreach($data as $k=>$v)
{
    // Building the sql query:
    $str[]='('.(int)$v.','.($tot_objects-$k).')';
}

$str = 'VALUES'.join(',',$str);



// This will limit voting to once a day per IP:
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO `sort_votes` (ip,date_submit,dt_submit,userOrder,Tablename)
                VALUES       ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',NOW(),NOW(),$userOrder,$tablename)");

//  If the user has not voted before today:
if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
{

mysql_query('   INSERT INTO `IFC` (id,votes) '.$str.'
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE votes = votes+VALUES(votes)');
}


  }
```

my main index page is in php. my question is, why is no AJAX post request being made when the function is called?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in your browser's console? In addition, please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: How are you calling that function? It's probably the case that you've also got a `<form>` on the page, and that the form is being submitted.

Comment: yes, by default it's asynchronous. You have to explicitly say you want a synchronous call. Your sql code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and probably suffering from syntax errors as well - since you have absolutely NO error handling in there, you'll never be able to tell.

Comment: Are there any errors on your console?

Comment: You might need to prevent the default behavior of the submit too.

Comment: yes it is asynchronous until you specify it to be synchronous explicitly.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your events not the functions itself. We can't tell how you register the onclick event and if you are stoping the submit event, so more html and/or js code is required to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$.POST` and all other AJAX calls are asynchronous by default, but you can make it synchronous by [changing `async` to `false`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

A better fix though would be to prevent event propagation. Because the call is asynchronous, the function `submitvote` continues to execute, and you have nothing in to prevent it from propagating the event to other listeners. To fix this, you should `return false` at the bottom of `submitvote`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for more details.

Also, you should probably use [`$.submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) to listen to form submissions rather than button clicks. This will capture, e.g. form submissions done via keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) By default, all ajax requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. `async` set to `true` by default). If you need synchronous requests, set `async: false`.

**`$.post()` is a shorthand Ajax function**

As for your problem, I would assume (and also suggest that) your submit event look like the following provided you've a voting form (like the one at the end).

```
$('#myForm').on("submit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    submitvote("yourParam");
});

function submitvote(uv) {
    $('#rank_IFC').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif">').show();
    var sortdata = $('ul.sort').sortable('toArray').join(',');
    var url= "results.php";
    $.post(url, {Tablename:uv, sortdata: sortdata}, function(){
        $('#rank_IFC').html('').show();
    });
}
```

And the form may look like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <!-- ... more input elemenst -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Me" />    
</form>
```